# How to snap an active vertex to a face

Tags: objects, snapping

I'm trying to slide an edge along it's normal and snap the active vertex exactly on the face. I'm trying in the GIF with face snapping+active on but it doesn't work. It it somehow possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to snap one edge of the prism face to the cube face?
 What is the desired end result? Easiest way would be to select all and in Ctrl+F menu use Knife (Intersect) with Self Intersect mode, then remove extra geometry; sliding along edge while snapping afaik isn't possible.